# Creating a Correlation Matrix between Types in a Column based on Date Column in SAS

Tags: sas, correlation

I have a table that looks like this:

```
product_type    sales   date
A               470     1/1/2017
A               233     1/2/2017
A               312     1/3/2017
A               139     1/4/2017
A               343     1/5/2017
A               234     1/6/2017
B               441     1/1/2017
B               175     1/2/2017
B               293     1/3/2017
B               109     1/4/2017
B               314     1/5/2017
B                55     1/6/2017
C               292     1/1/2017
C               212     1/2/2017
C               372     1/3/2017
C               452     1/4/2017
C               362     1/5/2017
C                 6     1/6/2017
```

I'm trying to create a correlation matrix that gives me the correlation by `product_type` based on the dates.  I need my output to look like this:

```
    A   B   C
A   1.0 0.8 0.1
B   0.2 1.0 0.2
C   0.6 0.2 1.0
```

The only way I know how to do this is by creating a new table breaking out each `product_type` into a column based on date like this:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select date
      ,sum(case when product_type = 'A' then sales else . end) as A
      ,sum(case when product_type = 'B' then sales else . end) as B
      ,sum(case when product_type = 'C' then sales else . end) as C
from work.data
group by 1;
quit;

proc corr data=work.test;
run;
```

This gets the matrix I want, but with a few dozen unique values in `product_types` it would be very time-consuming to write a line for each one.

I've also tried this:

```
proc corr data=data;
by product_type notsorted;
run;
```

But this just gets the correlation between date and sales, which is not what I'm looking for.

I tried this as well:

```
proc corr data=data;
by date product_type notsorted;
run;
```

I don't really know exactly what this code is doing, but it crashed my SAS.

Any thoughts on how to get this efficiently using the first table?

Comment: What does 0.8 represent, ie second value in first row (AxB)? Is that the correlation between A and B in all dates?

Comment: @Reeza yes, in all dates.

Comment: Then my answer below holds, TRANSPOSE and then CORR will give you the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reformat your data so that each product is a column and then you can find the correlation between the products. Use PROC TRANSPOSE to change your data from long to wide and then PROC CORR to create your matrix. This can be fully dynamic so if you add more products/dates it will still work. Otherwise you can do it manually via the SQL method you've shown above.

EDIT: here's sample code.

```
proc sort data=have;
by date product_type;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=wide prefix=PT_;
by date;
var sales;
id product_type;
idlabel product_type;
run;

proc corr data=wide;
var PT_:;
run;
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of variation of PROC TRANSPOSE, but I can't get it to replicate what the PROC SQL does in my example.  What I get instead is the `product_type` with `col1`, `col2`, `col3` etc.  I think that SAS is trying to create a correlation matrix between each column.  Do you know how to use PROC TRANSPOSE to get it in the same format as the PROC SQL puts it?

Comment: You missed some parts of PROC TRANSPOSE most likely. See the code above.